# Validation didnt work well after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

```js
$(function(){
        $("form").validate(
            {
                rules:
                {
                    username: {required: true},
                    email: {required: true, email: true},
                },
                messages:
                {
                    username: {required: 'Please enter your username'},
                    email: {required: 'Please enter your email address', email: 'Please enter a VALID email address'},
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
input.error,
select.error,
select.error,
textarea.error{
    background: #fff0f0;
    border: 2px solid #ee9393;
}
.error{
    color: #ee9393;
}
input.valid,
select.valid,
select.valid,
textarea.valid{
    background: #e3ffd4;
    border: 2px solid #6fb679;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>  
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">  
</label>
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
</label>
<button type=submit>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

I use **[jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)** to check form. I have little problem with one of my field.

1) When user enter some text in "username" field, its became green which mean field is valid.

2) Then I press submit button. As you see from the picture "email" field became red cause it was empty.

3) After that I deleted the text from the "username" field but its still green while color of the field must change to red.
[image]

So my **question** is how to change that strange behavior with 'username' field?!

Comment: Following the steps you describe, it seems that the user field becomes red when you empty it?

Comment: It should turn red when you either a) lose focus from that field; or b) try submitting

Comment: you just need to validate the form again  on a keyUp event

Comment: In real browser as I described first I enter text in username field then press submit button. Username field became green. After that I deleted all text but it still green. It must be red cause field is empty. So I am comfused why it happenes. It works normal if I didnt press submit button. Fields became red when they are empty. Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: @volkinc You mean I need to add onkeyup: false ?

Comment: When you delete the letters from a field something should invoke the check of the fields, So, it's good to add form validation also on keyUP event. if you delete letters from field and del button will be released   it will call validate and it will paint your fiels to the right color

Comment: I'm surprised but in stackoverflow snippet it works not as in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation plugin from https://jqueryvalidation.org/ triggered when you submit the form. The issue is, you only clear the username field without resubmit it. You can try validation on keyup event to that field. Here's the example, you just need to define the border color or another css properties in red class.

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('red');
    $(this).after('<div class="err-msg">Please fill this field</div>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for example. I just want to say that also we need to use  $(this).removeClass('valid');

Comment: Can I ask one more question. How here to add error label message?! I mean where exactly here I can declare errorPlacement: function?

Comment: you can add this script to if condition : $(this).after('<div class="err-msg">Please fill this field</div>');